# Flowtype allow any strings except a specific value

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to figure out how to properly type a tricky case. The use case is that we have an API offering a lot of generic breakdown filters (dimension + function combination), but in some specific case (like a date dimension) we want to limit the allowed `function` values.

Here's what I have right now:

```
// @flow

type Breakdown =
    | {
          dimension: 'date',
          function: 'day' | 'week' | 'month' | 'year',
      }
    | {
          dimension: string,
          function?: string,
      };

// This should fail
const val: Breakdown = {
    dimension: 'date',
    function: 'foo-bar'
};
```

Demo: https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AIQE5YCGA1gCYIB2oAvIqA6AD6gDe9jnDZAlgLZZKAZx6xKALlAByMkRRYpAGg5dGkAK6UAxilETpstFObT4WLCWMspfMSgAWV6WmL4lKxgF8PLdqs68AsJ6kkIo+DyUAObK-mqaOnoA-KHhkTEeDJ4A3MggoAAq9jxCoEL2sOrQZKCQRDzQiFpiYaAAbkTQkgTE5FS0bB6BgiJikjJyCrHx2rpj0pCwsAC0AEZEbog5iEA

The issue is that the generic matcher will always match everything.

Is there anyway to tell flow allow all `string` except `"date"`? Or maybe my current approach is wrong?

Comment: _"Is there anyway to tell flow allow all string except "date"?_ -- That makes no sense. Flow is a STATIC checker, you are asking for runtime checks. You an statically check either `string` (the generic type) OR a list of specific strings. How is Flow supposed to statically(!) check a combination of the generic type and concrete string instances? _(Answer: It can't.)_

Comment: How is my code example dynamic? I don't want to validate against runtime values, just the static call sites (exactly like the demo code I provided).

Comment: You tell Flow it is a `string`! Please THINK about this and about what I wrote. _Over and out :-)_

Comment: `"date"` is a string literal type and hence a subtype of `string`. Since Flow doesn't have a "not type" there is nothing you can do except to list all other possible string literals besides `"date"`.

Comment: @ftor Even if Flow have a "not ..." option, as I explained, there is no way for Flow to do anything. He declared the variable could be any string - Flow has no way to check against specific strings statically. It looks at a variable and thinks "I'm told that this variable is allowed to hold _any_ string.". Even if Flow checks all static string assignments, being told that there could be _anything_ during runtime, and that this is okay, would prevent it from being able to declare "this variable will never be XYZ". Either OP controls all possible values or he doesn't, can't have it both ways.

Comment: I understand why my current case and approach is not working. I'm wondering how one would handle this without listing all possible alternative values.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias probably the best approach is never to declare `val` as an object literal, but to instead have a function that generates a `Breakdown` object (or class instantiation, or tuple, or whatever—the implementer would just pass this to something else and not care what type it is). That function could then have all your logic for what two arguments are compatible. Simply, the business rules you have are too complex for Flow's use case, which stops at verifying that the type of the arguments are correct.